# Blacking out or blurring screenshots/screen recordings in flutter iOS app

Tags: ios, flutter, screenshot

I would like for my flutter app to not allow screenshots for privacy. On android this is simple, I just used the flutter_windowmanager package. On iOS, there doesn't seem to be a clear way to block screenshots. However, I have run into some iOS apps like PicsArt and Facetune that you can screenshot but the image will just be completely black. Do you guys know any methods to do this? Or even just blur the final screenshot?